# Check a string to see if it contains one of the strings in a array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Been scratching my head all morning and cannot seem to think of a logical quick way of doing this, without using alot of resources.

Here is the scenario,

```
$content = "hello this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it";
$arrayto = array("good morning","hello","good afternoon","morrow");
$website = "http://www.google.com";
```

I would like to check the $content and if it contains one of the arrays words and if it does turn it into a link using the `$website` as the `href=""`, and then stop as soon as it finds one.

So then `$content` would be `"<a href="$website">hello</a> this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it";`.

Thanks

Comment: This can be done with simple `preg_replace` inside `foreach` loop. Have you given it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without Regex using `str_replace`

```
 <?php
    $content = "hello this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it";
    $arrayto = array("good morning","hello","good afternoon","morrow");
    $website = "http://www.google.com";

    foreach($arrayto as $v){
     if(strpos($content,$v)!==false){
   $content= str_replace("$v","<a href=$website>$v</a>",$content);
        }
    }
    echo $content;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/137845)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**:

```
<a href=http://www.google.com>hello</a> this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it
```

Answer (score 1):

Source [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)    `str_replace` could be an answer

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
    $phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
    $healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
    $yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

    $newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Comment: Maybe you could extend your answer with the real values? Since this is the best answer up to now.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it-

```
<?php

$content = "hello this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it";
$arrayto = array("good morning","hello","good afternoon","morrow");
$website = "http://www.google.com";

$data=explode(' ', $content);
$final=array();

foreach ($data as $key ) {

    if(array_search($key, $arrayto))
    {
        $word='<a href='.$website.'>'.$key."</a>";
        array_push($final, $word);
    }
    else
    {
      array_push($final, $key);
    }
}

$res=implode(' ', $final);

print_r($res);

?>
```

OUTPUT- [hello](http://www.google.com) this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "hello this is a lovely website that people help me with and i love it";
$arrayto = array("good morning","hello","good afternoon","morrow");
$website = "http://www.google.com";
while($item = each($arrayto)){
    if(strstr($content, $item['value'])!==false){
        $content = str_replace($item['value'], '<a href="'.$website.'">'.$item['value'].'</a>', $content);
        break;
    }
}
```

You can use function [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in an efficient way without looping using `preg_replace`:

```
$content = "hi hello and bye";
$words = array('hello', 'bye');
$website = "http://www.google.com";

$regex = '/\b(' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b/';
echo preg_replace($regex, "<a href='$website'>$1</a>", $content, 1);
```

Note that regexes and `\b` bits are necessary if you want to replace whole words only, otherwise it turns `helloween` into `<a...>hello</a>ween`.